# How to calculate revenue for each month?

Tags: sql, sql-server

The data provided is for a recurring revenue (per month) and the column definitions are below:

- Customer ID - Account Field (not unique)
- Contract start date – Opp Start Date
- Contract end date – OPP contract end date
- Contract value – MRR(expected revenue per month)

| Opp Start Date | OPP contract end date | Account Field | MRR(expected revenue per month) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1/2/2013 | 1/2/2015 | 50e55 | 195.00 |
| 1/2/2013 | 1/2/2014 | 4ee75 | 50.00 |
| 1/2/2013 | 1/2/2014 | 4f031 | 75.00 |
| 1/2/2013 | 1/2/2016 | 4c3b2 | 133.00 |
| 1/2/2013 | 1/2/2016 | 49ec8 | 132.00 |
| 1/3/2013 | 1/3/2014 | 49fc8 | 59.00 |
| 1/4/2013 | 1/4/2015 | 49wc8 | 87.00 |
| 12/27/2013 | 12/27/2014 | 50bf7 | 190.00 |
| 12/27/2013 | 12/27/2014 | 59bb8 | 179.00 |
| 12/27/2013 | 12/27/2014 | 49ec8 | 147.00 |

Specifically, over a rolling 12 month period I would like to allocate revenue in each month to the following categories:

1. Up-sell – an overall increase in revenue from existing customers spending more than they did 12 months ago (includes new/expired contracts of existing customers)
2. Down-sell – a overall decrease in revenue from existing customers spending less than they did 12 months ago (includes new/expired contracts of existing customers)
3. Churn – a decrease in revenue from customers leaving (i.e. they were a customer 12 months ago, but no longer are a customer; i.e. their last contracts have expired)
4. New customers – an increase in revenue from new customers (i.e. those who weren’t customers 12 months ago; based on the first new contracts of customers.)

How can I achieve this in SQL?

Expected result (proposed), given the above data:

```
+---------+---------+--------+----------+---------+--------+
| Month   | MRR     | upsell | downsell | newsell | churn  |
+---------+---------+--------+----------+---------+--------+
| 2013-01 |  731.00 |   NULL |     NULL |  731.00 |   NULL | (195+50+75+133+132+59+87)
| 2013-02 |  731.00 |   NULL |     NULL |  731.00 |   NULL |
| 2013-03 |  731.00 |   NULL |     NULL |  731.00 |   NULL |
| 2013-04 |  731.00 |   NULL |     NULL |  731.00 |   NULL |
| 2013-05 |  731.00 |   NULL |     NULL |  731.00 |   NULL |
| 2013-06 |  731.00 |   NULL |     NULL |  731.00 |   NULL |
| 2013-07 |  731.00 |   NULL |     NULL |  731.00 |   NULL |
| 2013-08 |  731.00 |   NULL |     NULL |  731.00 |   NULL |
| 2013-09 |  731.00 |   NULL |     NULL |  731.00 |   NULL |
| 2013-10 |  731.00 |   NULL |     NULL |  731.00 |   NULL |
| 2013-11 |  731.00 |   NULL |     NULL |  731.00 |   NULL |
| 2013-12 | 1247.00 |   NULL |     NULL | 1247.00 |   NULL | (731+190+179+147)
| 2014-01 | 1247.00 | 147.00 |     NULL |  369.00 |   NULL | (Account='49ec8' added 147. The rest are new Account contracts. Year over year this month)
| 2014-02 | 1063.00 | 147.00 |     NULL |  369.00 | 184.00 |
| 2014-03 | 1063.00 | 147.00 |     NULL |  369.00 | 184.00 |
| 2014-04 | 1063.00 | 147.00 |     NULL |  369.00 | 184.00 |
| 2014-05 | 1063.00 | 147.00 |     NULL |  369.00 | 184.00 |
| 2014-06 | 1063.00 | 147.00 |     NULL |  369.00 | 184.00 |
| 2014-07 | 1063.00 | 147.00 |     NULL |  369.00 | 184.00 |
| 2014-08 | 1063.00 | 147.00 |     NULL |  369.00 | 184.00 |
| 2014-09 | 1063.00 | 147.00 |     NULL |  369.00 | 184.00 |
| 2014-10 | 1063.00 | 147.00 |     NULL |  369.00 | 184.00 |
| 2014-11 | 1063.00 | 147.00 |     NULL |  369.00 | 184.00 |
| 2014-12 | 1063.00 |   NULL |     NULL |    NULL | 184.00 |
| 2015-01 |  547.00 |   NULL |  -147.00 |    NULL | 553.00 |
| 2015-02 |  265.00 |   NULL |  -147.00 |    NULL | 651.00 |
| 2015-03 |  265.00 |   NULL |  -147.00 |    NULL | 651.00 |
... etc.
```

Note: up-sell and down-sell cases require Accounts to be capable of having multiple associated Contracts (example: Account = '49ec8').

The test case:

```sql
CREATE TABLE contracts (
     StartDate  DATE
   , EndDate    DATE
   , Account    VARCHAR(20)
   , MRR        DECIMAL(8,2)
);

INSERT INTO contracts VALUES
  ('1/2/2013'      ,  '1/2/2015'      ,          '50e55',     195.00)
, ('1/2/2013'      ,  '1/2/2014'      ,          '4ee75',     50.00)
, ('1/2/2013'      ,  '1/2/2014'      ,          '4f031',     75.00)
, ('1/2/2013'      ,  '1/2/2016'      ,          '4c3b2',     133.00)
, ('1/2/2013'      ,  '1/2/2016'      ,          '49ec8',     132.00)
, ('1/3/2013'      ,  '1/3/2014'      ,          '49fc8',     59.00)
, ('1/4/2013'      ,  '1/4/2015'      ,          '49wc8',     87.00)
, ('12/27/2013'    ,  '12/27/2014'    ,          '50bf7',     190.00)
, ('12/27/2013'    ,  '12/27/2014'    ,          '49cc8',     179.00)
, ('12/27/2013'    ,  '12/27/2014'    ,          '49ec8',     147.00)
;
```

Comment: @Jon Armstrong. But here you are creating tables and inserting right?. Can you pls help me to achieve your above answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's my attempt, which generated the partial results shown in the question.  There are a number of ways to do this.  I chose to do this mainly with window functions, and not outer joins.  Either is usable.

[The fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=29a06fdd52bb596d20645479ac3f2185)

| CTE Term | Description |
| --- | --- |
| expand | Recursively generate the monthly revenue rows for each contract |
| step0 | Sum the revenue per Account per month |
| step1 | Find the prior year (month) revenue per account |
| step1 | ... Also find the next year (month) revenue per account, used to add rows representing accounts with no further contracts |
| step2 | Combine Last Year MRR detail with rows representing accounts with no further contracts |
| step3 | With the above: calculate upsell, downsell, newsell, churn |
| Final expression | SUM and generate results per month |

```sql
WITH expand (StartDate, EndDate, Account, MRR, CurrDate) AS (
       SELECT c.*, CAST(CONCAT(LEFT(StartDate,7), '-01') AS date) FROM contracts AS c UNION ALL
       SELECT StartDate, EndDate, Account, MRR, DATEADD(month, 1, CurrDate) FROM expand
        WHERE CurrDate < EndDate
     )
   , step0 AS (
       SELECT Account, SUM(MRR) AS MRR, CurrDate, COUNT(*) AS n
         FROM expand
        GROUP BY Account, CurrDate
     )
   , step1 AS (
       SELECT *
            , LAG( MRR, 12) OVER (PARTITION BY Account ORDER BY CurrDate) AS LYMRR
            , LEAD(MRR, 12) OVER (PARTITION BY Account ORDER BY CurrDate) AS MRR2
         FROM step0
     )
   , step2 AS (
       SELECT Account, MRR, CurrDate, n, LYMRR FROM step1 UNION ALL
       SELECT Account, MRR2 AS MRR, DATEADD(year, 1, CurrDate) AS CurrDate, 0 AS n, MRR AS LYMRR
         FROM step1
        WHERE MRR2 IS NULL
     )
   , step3 AS (
       SELECT Account, MRR, CurrDate, n, LYMRR
            , CASE WHEN MRR > LYMRR   THEN MRR - LYMRR END AS upsell
            , CASE WHEN MRR < LYMRR   THEN MRR - LYMRR END AS downsell
            , CASE WHEN LYMRR IS NULL THEN MRR         END AS newsell
            , CASE WHEN   MRR IS NULL THEN LYMRR       END AS churn
         FROM step2
     )
SELECT LEFT(CurrDate, 7) AS Month
     , SUM(MRR)      AS MRR
     , SUM(upsell)   AS upsell
     , SUM(downsell) AS downsell
     , SUM(newsell)  AS newsell
     , SUM(churn)    AS churn
  FROM step3
 GROUP BY CurrDate
 ORDER BY CurrDate
;
```

The result:

```
+---------+---------+--------+----------+---------+--------+
| Month   | MRR     | upsell | downsell | newsell | churn  |
+---------+---------+--------+----------+---------+--------+
| 2013-01 |  731.00 |   NULL |     NULL |  731.00 |   NULL | (195+50+75+133+132+59+87)
| 2013-02 |  731.00 |   NULL |     NULL |  731.00 |   NULL |
| 2013-03 |  731.00 |   NULL |     NULL |  731.00 |   NULL |
| 2013-04 |  731.00 |   NULL |     NULL |  731.00 |   NULL |
| 2013-05 |  731.00 |   NULL |     NULL |  731.00 |   NULL |
| 2013-06 |  731.00 |   NULL |     NULL |  731.00 |   NULL |
| 2013-07 |  731.00 |   NULL |     NULL |  731.00 |   NULL |
| 2013-08 |  731.00 |   NULL |     NULL |  731.00 |   NULL |
| 2013-09 |  731.00 |   NULL |     NULL |  731.00 |   NULL |
| 2013-10 |  731.00 |   NULL |     NULL |  731.00 |   NULL |
| 2013-11 |  731.00 |   NULL |     NULL |  731.00 |   NULL |
| 2013-12 | 1247.00 |   NULL |     NULL | 1247.00 |   NULL | (731+190+179+147)
| 2014-01 | 1247.00 | 147.00 |     NULL |  369.00 |   NULL | (Account='49ec8' added 147. The rest are new Account contracts. Year over year this month)
| 2014-02 | 1063.00 | 147.00 |     NULL |  369.00 | 184.00 | (churn = 50+75+59 accounts with no further contracts)
| 2014-03 | 1063.00 | 147.00 |     NULL |  369.00 | 184.00 |
| 2014-04 | 1063.00 | 147.00 |     NULL |  369.00 | 184.00 |
| 2014-05 | 1063.00 | 147.00 |     NULL |  369.00 | 184.00 |
| 2014-06 | 1063.00 | 147.00 |     NULL |  369.00 | 184.00 |
| 2014-07 | 1063.00 | 147.00 |     NULL |  369.00 | 184.00 |
| 2014-08 | 1063.00 | 147.00 |     NULL |  369.00 | 184.00 |
| 2014-09 | 1063.00 | 147.00 |     NULL |  369.00 | 184.00 |
| 2014-10 | 1063.00 | 147.00 |     NULL |  369.00 | 184.00 |
| 2014-11 | 1063.00 | 147.00 |     NULL |  369.00 | 184.00 |
| 2014-12 | 1063.00 |   NULL |     NULL |    NULL | 184.00 |
| 2015-01 |  547.00 |   NULL |  -147.00 |    NULL | 553.00 |
| 2015-02 |  265.00 |   NULL |  -147.00 |    NULL | 651.00 |
| 2015-03 |  265.00 |   NULL |  -147.00 |    NULL | 651.00 |
| 2015-04 |  265.00 |   NULL |  -147.00 |    NULL | 651.00 |
| 2015-05 |  265.00 |   NULL |  -147.00 |    NULL | 651.00 |
| 2015-06 |  265.00 |   NULL |  -147.00 |    NULL | 651.00 |
| 2015-07 |  265.00 |   NULL |  -147.00 |    NULL | 651.00 |
| 2015-08 |  265.00 |   NULL |  -147.00 |    NULL | 651.00 |
| 2015-09 |  265.00 |   NULL |  -147.00 |    NULL | 651.00 |
| 2015-10 |  265.00 |   NULL |  -147.00 |    NULL | 651.00 |
| 2015-11 |  265.00 |   NULL |  -147.00 |    NULL | 651.00 |
| 2015-12 |  265.00 |   NULL |  -147.00 |    NULL | 651.00 |
| 2016-01 |  265.00 |   NULL |     NULL |    NULL | 282.00 |
| 2016-02 |    NULL |   NULL |     NULL |    NULL | 265.00 |
| 2016-03 |    NULL |   NULL |     NULL |    NULL | 265.00 |
| 2016-04 |    NULL |   NULL |     NULL |    NULL | 265.00 |
| 2016-05 |    NULL |   NULL |     NULL |    NULL | 265.00 |
| 2016-06 |    NULL |   NULL |     NULL |    NULL | 265.00 |
| 2016-07 |    NULL |   NULL |     NULL |    NULL | 265.00 |
| 2016-08 |    NULL |   NULL |     NULL |    NULL | 265.00 |
| 2016-09 |    NULL |   NULL |     NULL |    NULL | 265.00 |
| 2016-10 |    NULL |   NULL |     NULL |    NULL | 265.00 |
| 2016-11 |    NULL |   NULL |     NULL |    NULL | 265.00 |
| 2016-12 |    NULL |   NULL |     NULL |    NULL | 265.00 |
| 2017-01 |    NULL |   NULL |     NULL |    NULL | 265.00 |
+---------+---------+--------+----------+---------+--------+
```

The setup:

```sql
CREATE TABLE contracts (
     StartDate  DATE
   , EndDate    DATE
   , Account    VARCHAR(20)
   , MRR        DECIMAL(8,2)
);

INSERT INTO contracts VALUES
  ('1/2/2013'      ,  '1/2/2015'      ,          '50e55',     195.00)
, ('1/2/2013'      ,  '1/2/2014'      ,          '4ee75',     50.00)
, ('1/2/2013'      ,  '1/2/2014'      ,          '4f031',     75.00)
, ('1/2/2013'      ,  '1/2/2016'      ,          '4c3b2',     133.00)
, ('1/2/2013'      ,  '1/2/2016'      ,          '49ec8',     132.00)
, ('1/3/2013'      ,  '1/3/2014'      ,          '49fc8',     59.00)
, ('1/4/2013'      ,  '1/4/2015'      ,          '49wc8',     87.00)
, ('12/27/2013'    ,  '12/27/2014'    ,          '50bf7',     190.00)
, ('12/27/2013'    ,  '12/27/2014'    ,          '49cc8',     179.00)
, ('12/27/2013'    ,  '12/27/2014'    ,          '49ec8',     147.00)
;
```